# Laravel filter with pivot table based on user id

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

seeking for a help. I have this code below but it cannot execute the query of search. I just need to view only the data of search based on the user id.

```
$id = Auth::id();
            
            $promo = User::with('promos');

            if($request->input('q')){
                
                $promo->whereHas('promos', function ($query) use ($request) {
                    $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('q')}%");
                });
                
                return view('admin.promo.index',[
                    'promos' => $promo->find($id)
                ]);
            }

            return view('admin.promo.index',[
                'promos' => $promo->find($id)
            ]);
```

Comment: what part of this isn't working as you need it to? and can you rephrase what you are actually looking for

Comment: Hi @lagbox, if user logged in they just see all the promos that incorporated to him thats why I am using find($id). But the problem was I can't do execute the search query, if the user search promo the result should be the incorporated promos under him

Comment: why can't you execute the search query?  do you actually need the user object here or do you just want their promos? (because you could just do the query from the `Promo` side instead of from `User`)

Comment: I just want their promos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the `Promo` side using `whereHas`:

```
return view('admin.promo.index', [
    'promos' => Promo::whereHas('user', fn ($q) => $q->whereKey(Auth::id()))
        ->when($request->input('q'), fn ($q, $input) => $q->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$input%"))
        ->get()
]);
```

You can use the `when` method instead of using an `if` statement.

Comment: Wow!! Your answer perfectly fits to my need. Thank you so much!